# Emgu CV "Emgu.CV.Util.CvException" when using GaussianBlur with size>3

Tags: c#, opencv, emgucv

I have a very strange problem when using Emgu CV's gaussian blur functionality. Blurring an image works fine when I use a kernel size of 1-3, but when I use a larger size, my application exits with the following message:

`Exception thrown: 'Emgu.CV.Util.CvException' in Emgu.CV.World.dll`

I'm working in Visual Studio, and it doesn't even give me the standard exception popup. It just exits and throws me back to the editor.

This is the code I've tried:

`CvInvoke.GaussianBlur(image, image, new Size(4, 4), 0, 0);`

`image._SmoothGaussian(4);`

Both examples give the same results.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/3.0.0/document/html/4d4fa4cc-0d74-ab37-10ee-2189d35beb81.htm

If you check the documentation, you can see if the size must in odd number. "4" is an even number.

for example:
CvInvoke.GaussianBlur(input, outputGaussian, new System.Drawing.Size(15, 15), 3);

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is you cannot use an even number for this method , you may only use a odd and positive number (1,3,5.....etc), this is defined by the original [OpenCV libraries](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html?highlight=gaussianblur#void%20GaussianBlur(InputArray%20src,%20OutputArray%20dst,%20Size%20ksize,%20double%20sigmaX,%20double%20sigmaY,%20int%20borderType)) .

The Parameters needed for this method are as follows:

- src – input image;
- dst – output image of the same size and type as
  src.
- **ksize** – Gaussian kernel size. **ksize.width and ksize.height can differ but they both must be positive and odd**. Or, they can be
  zero’s and then they are computed from sigma* .
- sigmaX – Gaussian kernel standard deviation in X direction
- sigmaY – Gaussian kernel standard deviation in Y direction. if both sigmas are zeros, they are computed from ksize.width and ksize.height
- borderType – pixel extrapolation
  method